# For D-BMAP arrival rate per time slot is same as the probability of an arrival in a single slot

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

If there is discrete-time batch markovian arrival process with parameter matrices ${\bf D}_k$, $k\geq 0$ then the mean arrival rate per time slot is given by $\lambda={\bf \pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty n{\bf D}_n{\bf e}$, where ${\bf \pi}$ is stationary vector for D-BMAP and ${\bf e}$ is column vector of all elements one. Now I can't understand how the probability of an arrival in a single slot be same $\lambda$. I think this probability should be ${\bf \pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\bf D}_n{\bf e}$. Please help me to understand. Thank you in advance.